# Change product price based on choosen weight

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, configurable-product-options

is that possible to change easily the price based on product weight ? And is that possible to select product weight ?

Let me explain :

My website will sell for example some flour in bag of 25kg. But I want, on the same page, to allow the customer to choose what weight he wants (if he want's so buy 2kg, 8,4kg or 9,9999kg).

How can I do that, knowing that I need the product SKU has to be the same than the 25kg product.

Comment: you can try with custom options for this.

Comment: Which option should I choose ?

Comment: you need to create new options according to your requirement.

Comment: I don't find something to change the weight

Comment: you do not want to change weight, but you need to create diffrent weight options which you like to offer to customer for selection from frontend.

Comment: I don't want to add this restriction, I want the user to choose himself any weight he wants

Comment: If you are think, to choose any weight, then you need to provide inputbox to customer where customer add the weight according to requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options here.

1. Simple products with custom options.
2. Configurable product with "weight" attribute as the configurable attribute.

In order to use the first option, you need to edit your product via backend and you will find a tab with the name "Custom Options". There you need to add "weight" as a custom option. You can find **[more details here](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html)**.

For the second option, you need to firstly create a configurable "weight" attribute either via backend or via a migration script. Then create a configurable product based on this attribute. Here you will **[get more details](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html)** for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can create configuration type products where you need to create weight attributes with drop-down type.